# Upgrade/Update Intellij 12

Tags: installation, upgrade, intellij

My Intellij shows me that a minor version is available for upgrade. How do I go about upgrading the current version. Do i have to create a new folder in /usr/share and change all references to the new version or is there a better way?

Answer (score 18):

Intellij requires root permissions for the built in update function to work.

1. Either start using sudo:

   ```
   sudo /opt/intellij-idea-ce/bin/idea.sh
   ```

   or give all users the ability to update Intellij, then start as yourself:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R o+rw /opt/intellij-idea-ce
   /opt/intellij-idea-ce/bin/idea.sh
   ```
2. Then restart the IDE, click 'Help', 'Check for updates...'

Comment: I dont think this answer is true. My installation lies somewhere in `~`, however the update dialog only offers "Download" (which opens Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

Just download the .zip, extract it, and run bin/idea.sh. Your previous settings etc should be retained when you run the new version.

If oracle jdk/jvm is not available on the path, you may need to specify the path to it directly. Place the following in idea.sh, as the first line:

```
export IDEA_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/jdkxxxxx
```

(Put your own path to the jdk in there)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JetBrains TOOLBOX](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/). It is an easy way to manage your installed IDEs

[image: Picture of JetBrains window]

Answer (score 0):

Best way is using JetBrains Toolbox App.

1. Download tar.gz file from https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/
2. Open terminal `cd opt`
3. `sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jetbrains-toolbox-1.xx.xxxx.tar.gz`
4. jetbrains-toolbox-1.xx.xxxx/jetbrains-toolbox

After install Toolbox you can easily update.